# How to set Environment Variables on EC2 instance via User Data

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set environment variables with EC2s user data, but nothing i do seems to work

here are the User data scripts i tried

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> echo "export HOST_URL=checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-23235232.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com" >> /env.sh 
> source /env.sh
> ```

And another:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> echo "#!/bin/bash" >> /env.sh
> echo "export HOST_URL=checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-67323523.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com" >> /env.sh 
> chmod +x /env.sh
> /env.sh
> ```

They both do absolutly nothing, and if i log in and issue the command `source /env.sh` or `/env.sh` it works. so this must be something forbidden that i  am trying to do.

Here is the output from `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` using -e -x

> ```
> + echo 'export HOST_URL=checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-2141709021.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com'
> + source /env.sh
> ++ export HOST_URL=checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-2141709022.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
> ++ HOST_URL=checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-2141709022.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
> ```

Still, `echo $HOST_URL` is empty

As requested, the full UserData script

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> set -e -x 
> echo "export HOST_URL=checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-2141709021.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com" >> /env.sh 
> source /env.sh
> /startup.sh staging 2649
> ```

Comment: Are you trying to set the environment variables for scripts that run later in the user-data, or do you want the variables available when you login to the server over SSH? Also, are you sure the AMI you are using supports user-data scripts?

Comment: 1: i am trying to set user data to an application that runs after that script.
2: yes user data scripts work, this is just an addition to a script that runs after that one

Comment: To be clear, the script you want the variables to be available to is also being called in your user-data script?

Comment: yes, the snippet is copy-paste from ec2 instance user data

Comment: Can you show the entire user-data script then? Where are you running `echo $HOST_URL`?

Comment: running it after i log in using ssh, i'll paste the entire script

Comment: See, I asked if you needed it in the user-data or later when you are logging in and you said you needed it in the user-data. It will be available later in the user-data script but not when you login via SSH. You would have to run `source /env.sh` after logging in, or add that command to your `.bashrc`, in order for it to be available when you login.

Comment: Ok sorry i misunderstood you. so the env variable HOST_URL should be available for everything that runs in the context of that script (meaning the startup.sh that i run after the source execution)?

Comment: I should note that a point of having secrests as env variables is the security. If someone finds their way into the system, they'll be on a separate process and won't see all the secrets. Putting them in user data and pulling them to bashrc, as suggested by many solutions, increases the security risk.

Answer (score 38):

One of the more configurable approach to define environment variables for EC2 instances, is to use [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/features/#Parameter_Store). This approach will make it easier to manage different parameters for large number of EC2 instances, both encrypted using [AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) as well as in plain text. It will also allows to change the parameter values with minimal changes in EC2 instance level. The steps are as follows.

- Define string parameters (Encrypted with KMS or Unencrypted) in [EC2 Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/) Parameter Store.
- In the IAM role EC2 assumes, give required permission to access the parameter store.
- Using the AWS CLI commands for EC2 System Manager, read the parameters and export to environment variables in User Data section using [Get-Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameter.html) or [Get-Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters.html) AWS CLI commands and [controlling command output](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html) as required.

e.g Using [Get-Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameter.html) command to retrieve db_connection_string parameter(Unencrypted).

```sh
export DB_CONNECTION=$(aws --region=us-east-2 ssm get-parameter --name 'db_connection' --query 'Value')
```

Note: For more details in setting up AWS KMS Keys, defining encrypted strings, managing IAM policies & etc., refer the following articles.

- [Securing Application Secrets with EC2 Parameter Store](https://blog.rackspace.com/securing-application-secrets-with-ec2-parameter-store)
- [Simple Secrets Management via AWS’ EC2 Parameter Store](https://medium.com/@mda590/simple-secrets-management-via-aws-ec2-parameter-store-737477e19450)

Comment: The above script gives me null.
Following worked for me
```export DB_CONNECTION=$(aws --region=ap-southeast-1 ssm get-parameters --names 'db_connection' --query "Parameters[0].Value")```

Comment: Similar to the above comment `--query 'Parameter.Value'` is what worked for me. If you run the command without the `--query` you should see the parameter structure, and thru that you should be able to figure out what exactly you need to query.

Comment: Also, if you've stored your e.g. database URL as a `SecureString` with KMS, then append `--with-decryption` to the `aws ssm` command above in order to get that value decrypted.

Comment: You also need to trim off the `"` characters unless you are handling that in your application code. Piping that command to `tr -d \"` did the trick for me.

Comment: @sam , you can use `--output text` to trim the quotes

Comment: You're the real MVP @stefan

Comment: This example does not work for me. I ended up using the other answer, ubuntu EC2 instance:
`#!/bin/bash`
`echo export DB_CONNECTION=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name 'DB_CONNECTION_SECRET' --query 'Parameter.Value' --with-decryption --region eu-west-1 --output text) >> /etc/profile`

Answer (score 25):

I find this to be a pretty easy way to set environment variables for all users using User Data.  It allows me to configure applications so the same AMI can work with multiple scenarios:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo export DB_CONNECTION="some DB connection" >> /etc/profile
echo export DB_USERNAME="my user" >> /etc/profile
echo export DB_PASSWORD="my password" >> /etc/profile
```

Now, all users will have DB_CONNECTION, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD set as environment variables.

Comment: Does not work for me. I got the error: `-bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied`. PS: I try with sudo too.

Comment: Good approach...I found that a little bit cleaner syntax on what gets echoed within the quotes worked perfectly.  `echo "export GOROOT=/usr/local/go" >> /etc/profile`

Comment: @DiegoSomar echo doesn't work with sudo. Use tee instead:  `echo export DB_CONNECTION="some DB connection" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile`

Comment: Best solution so far.

Comment: @DiegoSomar won't work with sudo, but you can use command "sudo su" to go to the root user then "echo export DB_CONNECTION="some DB connection" >> /etc/profile". It will work.

Comment: Will this requires source .profile command after setting env variables? will these available in the same bash session

Comment: If you are not seeing changes instantly, make sure to run `source /etc/profile`

Answer (score 20):

The user data script on EC2 executes at after boot *in its own process*. The environment variables get set in that process and disappear when the process exits. You will not see the environment variables in other processes, i.e., login shell or other programs for that matter.

You will have to devise a way to get these environment variables into whatever program needs to see them.

Where do you need these variables to be available? In `/startup.sh staging 2649`?

EDIT

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e -x 
export HOST_URL="checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-2141709021.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
/startup.sh staging 2649
```

Then edit `/startup.sh`, and put the following line on the top:

```sh
echo $HOST_URL > /tmp/var
```

Boot the instance, and then paste `/tmp/var` here.

Comment: the startup.sh runs a rails application, inside that rails application there is a use of that env variable

Answer (score 7):

You can add another shell script in `/etc/profile.d/yourscript.sh` which will contain the set of environment variables you want to add.

This script will run at every bootup and your variable will be available to all users.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-2' > ~/myconfiguration.sh
chmod +x ~/myconfiguration.sh
sudo cp ~/myconfiguration.sh /etc/profile.d/myconfiguration.sh
```

The above code creates a shell script to set environment variable for aws default region and copies it to `profile.d` .

Comment: After adding this, refresh the bash shell, 

command: `source /etc/profile`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo HOST_URL=\"checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-23235232.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com\" >> /etc/environment
```

I created an EC2 instance with Amazon **Linux AMI** 2018.03.0 and added this user data to it and it works fine.

Refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/58828) for more details.

Comment: Seems like the only answer here that takes into account that `export` should not be in `/etc/environment` in (and maybe `/etc/profile` too) according to https://askubuntu.com/a/58828/615301

Answer (score 2):

After doing the stuffs in the user data script, the process exits.
So, whatever environment variable you export will not be there in the next process. One way is to to put exports in the .bashrc file so that it gets available in the next session also.

```
    echo "export HOST_URL=checkEmai-LoadBala-ICHJ82KG5C7P-23235232.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Scripts entered as user data are executed as the root user. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html.

Answer (score 2):

From [this Medium.com article](https://medium.com/@seb.nyberg/passing-tags-as-environment-variables-to-an-ec2-instance-12b64e69891e), you can put a script in `UserData` that writes to a file in `/etc/profile.d` that will get run automatically when a new shell is run.

Here is an example `cloudformation.yaml`

```yaml
Parameters:
  SomeOtherResourceData:
    default: Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "SomeExportName"
Resources:
  WebApi:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      # ...
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub
          - |
            #!/bin/bash

            cat > /etc/profile.d/load_env.sh << 'EOF'

            export ACCOUNT_ID=${AWS::AccountId}
            export REGION=${AWS::Region}
            export SOME_OTHER_RESOURCE_DATA=${SomeOtherResourceData}

            EOF
            chmod a+x /etc/profile.d/load_env.sh
```

And a YAML that exports something

```yaml
# ...
Outputs:
  SomeExportName:
    Value: !Sub "${WebDb.Endpoint.Address}"
    Export:
      Name: SomeExportName
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the init script of the node will add environment variables on launch. They won't show up in the node configuration page but they will be able to use in any job.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/"' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile#
```

This answer is similar to what hamx0r proposed however, jenkins doesn't have permission to echo to `/etc/profiles` with or without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

This maynot be the exact answer to the OP's question but similar. I've thought of sharing this as I've wasted enough time searching for the answer and finally figured it out.

Example assuming - AWS EC2 running `ubuntu`.

If there is a scenario where you need to define the environment variables as well use it in the same bash session (same user-data process), then either you can add the variables to `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment` or `/home/ubuntu/.zshrc` file. I have not tried `/home/ubuntu/.profile` file BTW.

Assuming adding to `.zshrc` file,

```sh
sudo su ubuntu -c "$(cat << EOF 
    echo 'export PATH="/tmp:\$PATH"' >> /home/ubuntu/.zshrc
    echo 'export ABC="XYZ"' >> /home/ubuntu/.zshrc
    echo 'export PY_VERSION=3.8.1' >> /home/ubuntu/.zshrc
    source /home/ubuntu/.zshrc
    echo printenv > /tmp/envvars  # To test
EOF
)"
```

Once the user data is finished running, you can see the environment variables which you have added in the script are echoed to the `envvars` file. Reloading the bash with `source /home/ubuntu/.zshrc` made the newly added variables available in the bash session.

(additional info) How to install `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`?

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y zsh
sudo su ubuntu -c "$(cat << EOF 
    ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts
    git clone https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git /home/ubuntu/.oh-my-zsh
    cp /home/ubuntu/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template /home/ubuntu/.zshrc
    echo DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true" >> /home/ubuntu/.zshrc
    cp /home/ubuntu/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme /home/ubuntu/.oh-my-zsh/custom
EOF
)"
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh ubuntu
```

Wondering why I didn't added the environment variable in `.bashrc`? The scenario which I mentioned above (using the environment variables in the same user-data session) adding to `.bashrc` won't work. `.bashrc` is only sourced for interactive Bash shells so there should be no need for .bashrc to check if it is running in an interactive shell. So just like above,

```sh
source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
```

won't reload the bash. You can check this out written right in the beginning of the `.bashrc` file,

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what working for me

```
   UserData:
    Fn::Base64:
      !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "TEST=THISISTEST" >> /etc/environment
```

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way is definitely to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it creates for you everything you need with very small effort and have the easiest way in the entire AWS eco-system to set your environment variables.

check it out, there are also some exhaustive tutorials based on different languages
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-beanstalk/index.html

Comment: This answer isn't related to the question. You could add suggestions in a comment but it's not an answer.