# run docker-compose in EC2 user-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, user-data

I have an EC2 linux2 instance containing dokcer compose. I want the instance to start the docker service, navigate to the correct folder, and then run docker-compose up -d, three simple lines, every time the instance start:

```
sudo service docker start
cd APP
docker-compose up -d
```

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764145/amazon-ec2-user-data-how-does-it-work), entering this to the user data when the instance is stopped should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service docker start
cd APP
docker-compose up -d
```

But it does nothing. The [aws doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/) has also this script:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "Hello World" >> /tmp/testfile.txt  <<<<<<<<------- ACTUAL USER SCRIPT
--//
```

When I paste my three lines instead of the hello world line, only the first one, start the docker service, works.

I am new to Linux, so it is probably something small that I'm missing.

Thanks

EDIT
Thanks guys for your help, the issue is really the path to dir APP.

Comment: From your host go to `/var/log/cloud-init-output. log`. This will contain an errors outputted in your user-data

Comment: The user-data script runs as `root`, not as `ec2-user` so the shell paths, and home directories will be different. Because of that you should really use absolute paths in user-data scripts. For example `cd APP` may need to be `cd /home/ec2-user/APP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> entering this to the user data when the instance is stopped should work

The first attempt will sadly not work. This is because `UserData` [executes only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) when a new instance is **launched**.

> When I paste my three lines instead of the hello world line, only the first one

The second attempt fails because this script runs as `root` in `/` folder (**root of the filesystem**). So unless your APP is in `/APP`, this will not work.